# How to get current categorys root parent category and all its sub category

Tags: magento, parent, categories

I need  logic to show the category tree like below:

```
Cat1 -> cat11 -> cat111   
Cat2 -> cat21 -> cat211  
Cat3 -> cat31 -> cat311
```

So if I am in cat211, in the left column all the categories of its root parent category (Cat2) should be displaying. Eg. in magento

Cat2 -> Cat21 -> Cat211

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the category tree, And this should give you category tree. you can see the various filters being applied. (You can always do according to your need.)

```
<?php
$rootCatId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$catlistHtml = getTreeCategories($rootCatId, false);
echo $catlistHtml;

function getTreeCategories($parentId, $isChild){
$allCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active','1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu','1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $parentId))
            ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');

$class = ($isChild) ? "sub-cat-list" : "cat-list";
$html .= '<ul class="'.$class.'">';
foreach($allCats as $category)
{
    $html .= '<li><span>'.$category->getName()."</span>";
    $subcats = $category->getChildren();
    if($subcats != ''){
        $html .= getTreeCategories($category->getId(), true);
    }
    $html .= '</li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
return $html;
}

?>
```

> EDIT: getting all parent category using an id/current category id..

```
$id = Mage::registry('current_category'); //or if you are retrieving other way around
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);

$categorynames = array();
foreach ($category->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
    $categorynames[] = $parent->getName();
}
print_r($categorynames); //dumping category names for eg.
```

Comment: You mean to say current category's parent categories and subcategories, right ? I have updated my answer...

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `path` contains all parent ids in the form `1/root_id/parent_id/.../category_id`. You can use `$category->getPathIds()`  to retrieve it as an array (or `$category->getParentIds()` if you want to exclude the id of the category itself). Because the first id in the path is always "1", you should remove the first array item to start from the store root category:

```
$categoryIds = $category->getPathIds();
array_shift($categoryIds);
```

Then you can load these at once, using a collection:

```
$categoryCollection = $category->getCollection()->addIdFilter($categoryIds);
foreach ($categoryCollection as $categoryInPath) {

    // do what you want with $categoryInPath

}
```